# Query posts based on the meta key values of logged-in users?

Tags: custom-post-types, users, query-posts, user-meta

I searched in WordPress Codes, and all of the online forums and tutorials about this but could not find any relevant solution. What I am trying to achieve is to create a query that lists posts for a logged in user from the user specific meta key value.

Basically , users will click on a checkbox on frontend and mark the post as `Read`. Once they do so, a custom field value sets in the user meta table for that specific user. The value could be `True` or `False`.

For example if user `A` has marked post `1` as `Read (True)` and user `2` not, then the query will show only that post to user `A` only and not to user `B`.

Any guidance in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you tell if user A has read a specific post? like, if user A reads posts 1, 2,3 and 4, and user B reads posts 2, 4, 6 and 9, what does the meta table look like?

Comment: @Taruckus there is a checkbox present on each post. Any user who clicks on it, a value of `TRUE` will set in users_meta_table for that user only. In the same way if he unchecks it, a value of `FALSE` will be set.

Comment: What is the meta_key?

Comment: Meta Key = test_item_key and it has two values, either True or False.  Here is a screenshot from database  http://screencast.com/t/UTYpnSdW

Comment: how do you know which post the user was viewing when they checked the box?

Comment: @Milo there is a checkbox on each post. When a user will view that post, by default the checkbox will be set to Unchecked (a value of False) but if user ticks the checkbox then the value will change to `True`.  I hope I am clear now?

Comment: ok, say I'm user ID 3. given the key `test_item_key` with a value of `true`, can you tell me which post I marked as read?

Comment: Now I understand what are you talking about. I am not sure here how to do it. Actually this is the point I need help on. What I have in mind is that each post ID should be saved along with Meta key value but I dont know how to describe it correctly and implement.

Comment: probably the simplest way is to save an array of post IDs for each user. php has a number of functions to help you manage array values- adding, removing, etc.. you can then load a user's post ID array, and pass that directly as `post__in` argument in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Best way i think would be to add an array of read post IDs to the user meta table and use them in the 'post__not_in' Parameter in the pre_get_posts hook. In my mobile right now, so i will edit this answer once i'm at work to insert a code example.

Comment: any update on the code example?